# why angular.js transclude child childScope not inherit the parentScope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Thank you very much concerned about this issue, this problem is angular child scope not inherited from the parent scope when I use the transclude directive, this issue has a relationship with angular.js versions before 1.2.17 can work release, version 1.2.18 after are ineffective

These are two versions of the actual test results.
http://jsfiddle.net/a3ywb2c4/

```
var App= angular.module("myApp",[]);
App.controller("testCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.names= [{name:"janry",value:123},{name:"janry",value:123},{name:"janry",value:123}]
$scope.dd="hello world"
```

});

```
App.directive("testDire",function($parse){
return {
    restrict:'A',
    transclude:true,
    template:"<div  ng-repeat='$item in $items' ng-transclude></div>",
    scope:false,
    link:function(scope,iele,attrs,ctrl,transclude){
         var getter=$parse(attrs.data)
         scope.$items = getter(scope);     
    }
};
```

})

http://jsfiddle.net/m3fo9om3/

Answer (score 2):

This is how AngularJS is built: the scope for the transcluded directive is a **sibling** of the container directive, and they both inherit the parent scope.

[This post](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/) has very good explanations and work arounds.